# Convex hull of permutation applied on basis vector

Tags: permutations, convex-hulls

Given an ordered set of basis vectors $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with arbitrary order.
Apply any permutation $\sigma_i(B)$, it results in order of the basis. And I can cumulatively sum the basis with such order to form a set of vertices $V_i$.

For example, $B = \{ b_1, b_2, b_3 \}$, if $\sigma_1 = (1, 3, 2)$ Then $V_1 = \{b_1, b_1+b_3, b_1+b_3 + b_2 \}$. If $\sigma_2 = (1, 2, 3)$ then $V_2 = \{b_1, b_1+b_2, b_1+b_2+b_3 \}$.

Given $B$ and a set of permutations $S = \{ \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \cdots, \sigma_n\}$, how can one find the vertices of convex hull of $\cup_{i=1}^n V_i$ ?

A naive approach and be simply apply all the permutations to $B$ and then compute the convex hull of all possible points. But I'm wondering if there is any efficient way to do so?

Comment: no, $V_i$ won't require any order, we only interested in the convex hull of it

Comment: Is $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a typo or are you specifically interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$ case?

Comment: specifically interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$ case, but probably it can be generalized and makes an even harder problem? as Convex hull in high dimension is difficult

Comment: output of zonogos would implicitly assume the permutation set $S$ contains all permutations of $B$ which is not necessary true

Comment: You should have given this comment after my answer : in this way, I would have been informed of it. Otherwise, please prefix your answer by '@JeanMarie' or any other pseudo you want to reach.

Comment: sorry about that. i'll make sure of that next time :) @JeanMarie